# Using the "sizeof" operator on the column of an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

Sorry for the newbie question, I am still learning.

Let's say that I have `matrix[x][y]`

Using `sizeof(matrix)` will return me the whole size of the array.

Using `sizeof(matrix[a])` will return me the size of a certain row.

Using `sizeof(matrix[a][b])` will return me the size of what is located in [a][b].

Is there a way to just find the size of a column? If there is not, why? Am I overlooking something? Thanks for your time.

**EDIT: Thanks for the help, if someone else is looking for the answer the user "nnn" wrote the following:**

> For the number of elements in a column:
>
> ```
> sizeof(matrix) / sizeof(matrix[a])
> ```
>
> For the size in bytes occupied by a column:
>
> ```
> sizeof(matrix) / sizeof(matrix[a]) * sizeof(matrix[a][b])
> ```

**Also "Weather Vane" explains how sizeof works:**

> `sizeof` finds the extent of contiguous byte usage in memory, so it
>   can't be used directly to find the amount of memory used by each
>   column. The array, a row, or an element: yes. A column: no

Comment: The column elements are not consecutive in memory.

Comment: `sizeof` finds the extent of contiguous byte usage in memory, so it can't be used directly to find the amount of memory used by each column. The array, a row, or an element: yes. A column: no.

Comment: Oh, I get it now, thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the number of elements in a column, divide *matrix size* by *row size*:

```
sizeof(matrix) / sizeof(matrix[a])
```

For the size in bytes occupied by a column (the actual answer for the question), multiply *number of elements* (previous expression) by *element size*:

```
sizeof(matrix) / sizeof(matrix[a]) * sizeof(matrix[a][b])
```

Even if this can't be achieved by using a single `sizeof` operator, the `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time, and usually the compiler will substitute these arithmetic operations with the actual result, so there will be no runtime performance degradation caused by this.

Also, the usage of `a` and `b` in the expression above can be replaced by `0`,  i.e. `matrix[0]` and `matrix[0][0]`, because all the elements have the same size.

Comment: Also possible: `sizeof matrix / sizeof matrix[a]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is it maths :

```
columnsize = sizeof(matrix) / sizeof(matrix[a])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find size of a column, you must calculate this:

```
(number of rows)*(size of an element)
```

so for matrix[x][y] you must write this:

```
int sizeOfArrayColumn = x*sizeof(matrix[0][0]);
```